# find sbt plugins versions

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I am using some sbt plugins on a project and I would like to know which are their versions from sbt console.
I can type `plugins` which list the plugins but do not present their versions.
I want to do it from the sbt console, I do not want to inspect some plugins.sbt file or similar somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `plugins` command, you see references to the plugins as they are defined in the Scala code. A single artifact can contain many plugins. Those artifacts with plugins have versions and here's how you can see them.

1. First load the metaproject: `reload plugins`
2. Then check dependencies: `libraryDependencies`
3. Go back to your project: `reload return`

You can define an alias for this in your `~/.sbt/<version>/global.sbt`:

```
addCommandAlias("pluginsVersions", "; reload plugins ; libraryDependencies ; reload return")
```

It's not perfect, the output is noisy and not formatted nicely, but it's something you can get out of the box.